# Equation of Parabola through Four Points

Tags: equation-solving

```
{x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3}={-2.,3.,1.,-1.,4.,0};
soln=NSolve[{h^2==a b,a x^2+2 h x y+b y^2+2 f x+2 g y==1,a x1^2+2 h x1 y1+b y1^2+2 f x1+2 g y1==1,a x2^2+2 h x2 y2+b y2^2+2 f x2+2 g y2==1,a x3^2+2 h x3 y3+b y3^2+2 f x3+2 g y3==1},{a,b,h,f,g}]
```

Attempting to find constant coefficients from standard conic equation through three fixed points [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)] and a variable point $(x,y)$ along with a condition for parabola. Errors in realization of the second degree result. Appreciate all help.

```
EDIT1:
```

This worked earlier but does not, anymore.

```
   {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3} = {-2., 3, 1., -1, 4, 0};
equn = {h^2 == a b,
   a x^2 + 2 h x y + b y^2 + 2 f x + 2 g y == 1,
   a x1^2 + 2 h x1 y1 + b y1^2 + 2 f x1 + 2 g y1 == 1,
   a x2^2 + 2 h x2 y2 + b y2^2 + 2 f x2 + 2 g y2 == 1,
   a x3^2 + 2 h x3 y3 + b y3^2 + 2 f x3 + 2 g y3 == 1};
sol = NSolve[equn, {a, b, h, f, g}];
```

Comment: Remove `Reals`?

Comment: Thanks, removed *Reals*. Due to large output, shall be content with numerical solution, would like to see a parabola  plot.for three given points.

Comment: Up to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section ,  "Formally, given any **five** points in the plane in general linear position, meaning no three collinear, there is a unique conic passing through them, which will be non-degenerate; this is true in both the Euclidean plane and its extension, the real projective plane."

Comment: Thanks.Aware of this. Am trying to plot a parabola when the first invariant $I_1 = ab-h^2$  vanishes.

Comment: The `{x, y}` in `soln` and the `{x, y}` in the `ContourPlot` represent different things. Are you intention making them equal?  Consider the implications of `Chop@Table[
  aa x^2 + 2 hh x y + bb y^2 + 2 ff x + 2 gg y, {x, -2 + 0.001, 3.001,
    5/11}, {y, -2, 3, 5/12}]` on `ContourPlot`.

Comment: Maybe?: `Manipulate[
 x; y;
 ContourPlot[
  aa xx^2 + 2 hh xx yy + bb yy^2 + 2 ff xx + 2 gg yy == 1, {xx, -5, 
   5}, {yy, -5, 5}],
 {x, -2, 3}, {y, -2, 3},
 LocalizeVariables -> False
 ]`

Comment: Worked and then failed likely means variables need to be cleared...

Comment: I cleared all variables, including Global.